# Wordpress script causing load crash

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress site theme , there is a script called `HTTP://CONNECT.FACEBOOK.NET/EN_US/ALL.JS` which freezes my site before complete loading because the script can not connect to fb , where can I find the whole script and delete it? In which header file is that script placed? May it came from `Yoast  SEO social accounts`?
Thanks for your answering

Error message:

> www.facebook.com/impression.php/f3793911ddc5a7/?lid=115&payl‌​oad=%7B%22source%22%‌​3A%22jssdk%22%7D
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Actually the problem started when I changed the path of my website from `sub domain` to the `main domain` and already some .js files seem to point to the former location, I am confused with these problems.

Comment: sorry .... the script name is :connect.facebook.net

Comment: If you want to add or correct some information, edit your original question instead of adding comments.

Comment: Would you please share your website link and describe more , it may be can come from any plugins , and are you seeing nay error in console ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply , Yes , I am seeing this error in my console: 
www.facebook.com/impression.php/f3793911ddc5a7/?lid=115&payload=%7B%22source%22%3A%22jssdk%22%7D Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED                            actually the problem started when I changed the path of my website from "sub domain" to the "main domain" and already some .js files seem to point to the former location , I am confused with these problems.           Thanks a lot

Comment: Please share your website link so we help to track the issue